# Disable Jenkins build button

Tags: jenkins

I have few Jenkins job which builds with parameters.
Parameters are like Dev, Val and Prod.

Few jobs has only one parameter like Dev or Val or Prod. In these cases I would like to disable the Build button.

The Build button must be active only if all three parameters exists in the job.

Attached screenshot of it.

[image]

Help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: where is the screen shot you mentioned?

Comment: You might now click on 'Attachment' link to view the screenshot.

Comment: check this jenkins plugin ,. it should do the job :  https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Configuration+Slicing+Plugin